# Prove $deg(v) \geq \chi (G) - 1$ for every vertex in a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G$ be a loop-free undirected graph with vertex set $V$ satisfying
>   the condition $$ \chi (G) > \chi (G - v), \quad \forall v, v \in V$$
>
> $(i)$ Must $G$ be connected?
>
> $(ii)$ Prove that $deg(v) \geq \chi (G) - 1 \quad \forall v, v \in V$

For $(i)$, I think G must a complete graph since I could not find a graph that would satisfy above condition without making it complete. So for a complete graph $K_n$ the chromatic number is $\chi (G)=n$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: The [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) is an example of a graph that satisfies your condition, but is not a complete graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Yes. Indeed, let $G_1,\dots, G_k$ be the connected components of the graph $G$. It is easy to see that $\chi(G)=\sup_{k}\chi(G_k)$. 
If $k>1$ then pick any component $G_i$ such that there exists a component $G_j$, with $j\ne i$ and $\chi(G_j)\ge\chi(G_i)$. Then removal of any vertex $v$ of $G_i$ does not diminish $\chi(G)$, a contradiction.

(ii) Assume that there exists a vertex $v\in V$ such that  $deg(v)<\chi (G) – 1$. Pick a proper coloring of graph $G-v$ into at most $\chi(G)-1$ colors. Since $deg(v)<\chi (G) – 1$ we can extend this coloring to the vertex $v$ without using additional colors, a contradiction.