# Mycielski's construction-Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am unable to understand the significance of Mycielski's construction. What is so special about it that it is studied? What do we achieve in adding additional n+1 vertices and connecting them with original set in that specific manner

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian#Properties

Comment: I have seen that link. It does not give significance or reasons as to why this graph is studied. Nor do any of the textbooks that I have mentioned that.

Comment: I am mainly referring to sec 5.2 of Introduction to Graph Theory by Douglas West  where this topic is discussed. I can understand the construction method, but what is so special about it?

Comment: I guess what you're asking is not "what do we achieve", because there's a list of the properties we achieve on Wikipedia, but "why do we care?"

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you're just starting out thinking about the chromatic numbers graphs can have. In a lot of simple examples, the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ is equal to the clique number $\omega(G)$: the reason we can't use fewer than $\chi(G)$ colors is that there are $\chi(G)$ vertices, all adjacent to each other, which must be given different colors.

In fact, we see a lot of cases where this is "the reason" that a graph has its chromatic number. All planar graphs, for instance, can be $4$-colored. No planar graph can have a clique of size $5$.

The Mycielski construction gives us a sequence of graphs that have an arbitrarily high chromatic number for a different reason. In fact, their clique number stays at $2$: the Mycielski graphs don't even contain any triangles! Such graphs are hard to come up with by hand, so they're a good source of examples and counter-examples.

For instance, consider [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2532027/383078), in which we're looking for a graph whose chromatic number decreases whenever we delete a vertex. The user asking the question, who I promise I don't mean to pick on, conjectured that the only such graphs are complete graphs, which seems very reasonable at first if you try a few examples.

But if we start with any Mycielski graph, we'll get non-complete graphs with this property! In fact, Mycielski graphs have this property already. But even if they didn't, we could start with the Mycielski graph with chromatic number $100$, and keep deleting vertices for as long as this can be done without decreasing the chromatic number. The graph we get will definitely not be $K_{100}$, because the Mycielski graph didn't have a copy of $K_{100}$, but it will have chromatic number $100$ and the property we were looking for.

Comment: There's also a simpler, weaker construction in a similar spirit to the Mycielskian which lets us find a graph with $\chi(G)=r$, and $\omega(G) < r$ (note the Mycielskian gives $\omega(G) = 3$). For $r=3$, the cycle on five vertices works, and then simply add vertices which are connected to all existing vertices by induction to give a graph of sufficiently high $\chi(G)$ and $\omega(G)=\chi(G)-1$.

Comment: The Mycielskian gives $\omega(G)=2$, I believe, but yes.

Comment: Of course, my mistake.

Comment: That does make it clear. Yes I did  mean why do we care.....